# How do I get a winner in my program?

Tags: c++

I have my program almost done(it is a assignment in a c++ book I got on Amazon), however the last part is to display the winner of election. I have done this before put never when I read the information from a text file. If someone can direct me in the right direction, I will be very grateful. (Also if my code is not proper, please let me know how to improve it.)

TEXT FILE

```
Johnson 5000
Miller 4000
Duffy 6000
Robinson 2500
Ashtony 1800
```

CODE

```
/*Description: Reads data from text file, which has the number of votes each candidate received. 
Then calculates the total number of votes and get each candidates percentage of total votes. Finally displays the winner of election.
*/

//Libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

//Reads input text file name "votes.txt"
ifstream theFile("votes.txt");


//Variables
string name;
string winner;
int votes;
double percent;
int total=0;

//Sets console to two decimal places
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);


//Output column header to console
cout << left << setw(20) << "CANDIDATE";
cout << right << setw(20) << "VOTES RECEIVED";
cout << right << setw(30) << "% OF TOTAL VOTES\n";
cout << string(80, '-') <<  endl;



//Loops text file till cursor reads null
while (theFile >> name >> votes ) {



    //Equations
    //Made votes a double in order to get a decimal instead of a whole number
    percent = ((double)votes * 100) / 19300;
    total += votes;

    //Outputs result in console
    cout << left << setw(20) << name << right << setw(15) << votes << right << setw(28) << percent << endl;


}


//Outputs total to console
cout << left << setw(20) << "Total" << right << setw(16) << total << "\n" <<endl;
//Winner of the election
cout << "The Winner of the election is" << winner << endl;

//End program
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? This is not a code review site.

Comment: You can try posting on codereview.se. It's part of the same network of sites so you don't have to do any extra signup. Same feel. Go to the top bar that says "Stack Exchange" and search code review.

Comment: This may be on-topic for Code Review, assuming **a)** the code works **and b)** it isn't hypothetical or incomplete in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very obviously flaw is that your code already knows the total number of votes cast, 19300. As such, it would only work with this input data, and no other. A clear shortcoming.

The right solution should have no advance knowledge of the data, but rather be able to produce the right answer no matter how many candidates and total number of votes cast (ignoring the very obvious edge case of a tie, which is certainly out of scope here).

The expected solution is to read all the data into a `std::vector`, in advance. Having done that, either add up the number of votes to compute the total number of votes cast, or do that while reading the input data. In any case, once all the data is read and stored, go over all the data a second time, now computing the percentage for each candidate's number of votes (as a percentage of the total).

As far as determining the winner, this should be done by finding the candidate with the largest number of votes, rather than by comparing the percentages; again, a fairly simple Computer Science 101-type of a question.

One very common problem beginners run into, with this kind of a problem, is to try to code everything at once. Inevitably, the first attempt will have several bugs. The thing about bugs, is that having twice as many bugs doesn't mean that it typically takes twice as long to fix them.

Instead, the first thing you should do is just write the code that reads all the input data into a vector, and nothing more. After verifying that it works correctly, the next step is to write the step that computes the grand total of votes cast. And after verifying that this also works correctly, then finally finish the program by implementing the part that computs each candidate's percentage, and determines the winner.